# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ that make $f$ continuous everywhere (problem with $e$)

Tags: calculus

I need help with this problem. I need to find parameters $b$ and $c$ that make the function continuous everywhere. I don't know how to handle the number $e$.

[Here is the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVfHm.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :
$$b=8; 
 c=-4$$
You need to use Factorization.
The intuition for that is like the L'opitall rule $$ "\frac{0}{0}" $$ here you get that b must be 8.
then (x-4) is Reduced  and you left with:
$$ \Rightarrow  \lim_{x\to 4}\frac {(x-2)}{(x-3)}=2 $$.
 $$ 2e^{c+4} =2 \Rightarrow c=-4 $$

Comment: Thank you very much!